# How to phrase a request so "no" means "yes", and vice versa

Tags: meaning, phrases

How can I phrase a request so an answer of "no" actually accepts the request, and "yes" declines the request?

Comment: Go to politician's school.

Comment: @HotLicks *Would you mind* elaborating on that statement? ;)

Comment: @DanBron, By golly, you've done it!

Answer (score 2):

**There are a few ways.**

---

### Antonym

One way is to use an *antonym* of the operative word in the sentence.

> Is it impossible for you to take me?

In the above sentence, *impossible* is an antonym of *possible*. Thus, "*Yes*" would mean that it's impossible. "*No*" would mean that it is possible.

---

### Negative

Another method is to use a word with a *negative* implication, such as "trouble", "mind", "bother", "hate", "mortified", *etc*. For example, as @DanBrown cleverly posted in the question comments:

> Would you mind elaborating on that statement?

If someone answers "*No*", they are committing to answering. If they say "*Yes*", then they would not like to explain further.

---

### Sarcasm

And, of course, your question reminds me of this old tale:

> A linguistics professor was lecturing his college class one day. “In
>   English,” he said, “a double negative forms a positive. However, in
>   some languages, such as Russian, a double negative remains a negative.
>   But there isn’t a single language, not one, in which a double positive
>   can express a negative.”
>
> A voice from the back of the room piped up, “Yeah, right.”